# Azure Data Factory LOOKUP Activity issues

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following pipeline with a range of activities, see image below.

I keep on getting the error with my lookup activity

> Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
> database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid column
> name
> 'updated_at'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid
> column name 'updated_at'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data
> Provider,SqlErrorNumber=207,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=207,State=1,Message=Invalid
> column name 'updated_at'.,},],'

I kind of know what the problem is.. the lookup isn't looping through the individual tables to find the column name 'updated_at'.

But, I don't understand why.

The Lookup 'Lookup New Watermark' activity has the following query

```
SELECT MAX(updated_at) as NewWatermarkvalue FROM @{item().Table_Name}
```

The ForEach activity 'For Each Table' as the following for Items:

```
@activity('Find SalesDB Tables').output.value
```

The Lookup activity 'Find SalesDB Tables' has the following query

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(table_schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(table_name) AS Table_Name FROM information_Schema.tables WHERE table_name not in ('watermarktable', 'database_firewall_rules')
```

The only thing I can see that is wrong with the 'Lookup New Watermark' actvitiy is that its not looping through table. Can someone let me know what is needed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Just to show the column exists I adjusted the connection from
[image]

To the following:

[image]

And the Lookup was able to find the updated_at column on dbo.Products, but couldn't locate the updated_at column on the other 4 tables.

Therefore, I'm suggesting the problem is that the Lookup activity isn't iterating over the tables automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is when using the following query on a table that does not have `updated_at` column, we get this error.

```
SELECT MAX(updated_at) as NewWatermarkvalue FROM @{item().Table_Name}
```

- The *items* field in `for each` activity was given the value as `@activity('FindSalesDBTables').output.value` (returns a list of table names). Inside the for each, when we use the above query, it will be executed as following:

```
#first iteration
SELECT MAX(updated_at) as NewWatermarkvalue FROM <table_1>

#second iteration
SELECT MAX(updated_at) as NewWatermarkvalue FROM <table_2>
.
.
...
```

- During this process, when we use the above query on a table that does not have `updated_at` column, it gives the same error. The following is a demonstration of the same.
- I created 2 tables (for demonstration) called `t1 and t2`.

```
create table t1(id int, updated_at int)

create table t2(id int, up int)
```

- I used `look up` activity to get the list of table names using the following query:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(table_schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(table_name) AS Table_Name FROM information_Schema.tables WHERE table_name not in ('watermarktable', 'database_firewall_rules','ipv6_database_firewall_rules')
```

- Inside the `for each` activity (looping through **@activity('lookup1').output.value**), I have tried the same query as given.

```
SELECT MAX(updated_at) as NewWatermarkvalue FROM @{item().Table_Name}
```

After debugging the pipeline, we can observe that it produces the same error.

- For iteration where the table is `t1` (has *updated_at* column):

[image]

- For iteration where the table is `t2` (does not have *updated_at* column):

[image]

- If you publish and run this pipeline, the pipeline will fail giving the same error.
- Therefore, try to check if the `updated_at` column exists or not in the particular table (current for each item). If it does exist, proceed to query it.
- Inside `for each` use look up with the following query. It returns the length of column in bytes if the column exists in a table, else it returns null. Use this result along with `If condition` activity.

```
select COL_LENGTH('@{item().Table_Name}','updated_at') as column_exists
```

[image]

- Use the following condition in `If` activity. If it returns false, then it indicates that the particular table contains `updated_at` column and we can work with it.

```
@equals(activity('check for column in table').output.firstRow['column_exists'],null)
```

[image]

- The following is the debug output for the same (t1 and t2 tables)

[image]

You can continue with other required activities inside the False section of the `If condition` activity using above process.

Comment: Hi Saideep, thanks for reaching out. I have updated my question to address your comments about whether the column updated_at actually exists. It the columns definitely exists

Comment: ok, I just executed you code select ```COL_LENGTH('@{item().Table_Name}','updated_at') as column_exists``` and everything succeeded. Therefore, I guess this is further proof that the updated_at column exists, correct?

Comment: Yes, if the value returned by it is not `null` then it indicates that the column exists.

Comment: Do, you think the problem is with my code ```SELECT MAX(updated_at) as NewWatermarkvalue FROM @{item().Table_Name}```?

Comment: Debug the pipeline and look at the output it generates. That should help identify the issue.

Comment: Hi Saideep, yes they all have the updated_at column.

Comment: Just so you know, I have created the pipeline by following the guidelines in an excellent book called Data Engineering with Apache Spark, Delta Lake, and Lakehouse: Create scalable pipelines that ingest, curate, and aggregate complex data in a timely and secure way

Comment: Thanks for the information. Please debug and check what table names your `Find SalesDB Tables` lookup activity is returning. If it contains any additional tables (without `updated_at` column), that might be the cause for error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247287/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-patterson).